# Is it possible to add php code in an array? Trying to randomize the order of a dynamic lisy

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, random

**UPDATE**
Sorry. I wasn't as clear as I need to be I think. I am basically trying to insert more than a text string. The function is in wordpress and pulls in html code from the dashboard for ads.

```
   <ul id="randomOrderList">
        <li><?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('1'); } ?></li>
        <li><?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('2'); } ?></li>
        <li><?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('3'); } ?></li>
    </ul>
```

To this:

```
<ul id="randomOrderList">
    <li><a href="" title=""><img  src="name" alt=" " /></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title=""><img  src="name" alt=" " /></a></li>
    <li><a href="" title=""><img  src="name" alt=" " /></a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried this but I am not sure how to add the php in the array:

```
<?
  $array=array('<?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('1'); } ?>','<?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('2'); } ?>','<?php if (function_exists('dfrads')) { echo dfrads('3'); } ?>');
  shuffle($array);
  $array = array_chunk($array, 5);
  foreach($array as $section){
    echo '<ul id="randomOrderList">'."\n";
    foreach($section as $link){
      echo ' <li>'.$link.'</li>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</ul>'."\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: arrays intended to contain **data**, while code to output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your strings into an array :

```
$strings = array(
    'something 1', 
    'something 2', 
    'something 3', 
);
```

Without any kind of code -- **which is not permitted in there.**

Then, use the [**`shuffle()`**](http://fr.php.net/shuffle) function to randomize the array :

```
shuffle($strings);
```

And, now, loop over your array, to display the items :

```
echo '<ul id="randomOrderList">';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo '<li>' . $string . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

They will be displayed in random order.

**Edit after edit of the question :** you can construct the array calling your function, of course.

For example, you can use something like this :

```
$strings = array(
    dfrads('1'), 
    dfrads('2'), 
    dfrads('3'), 
);
```

If needed, you can include all your code inside a test for the existence of the `dfrads` function :

```
if (function_exists('dfrads')) {
    // Create the array
    // randomize it with shuffle
    // do the loop and the echos
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time Pascai. You solved the problem. it works great. Check it out. http://www.designclipboard.com/

Comment: @Design Clipboard: uhm, what is the difference with my answer?! o_O

Comment: Hi Zerkms, I tested your code and it worked just as well. So you both provided correct solutions. I think I just comprehended Pascal's solution faster. Thank you for your time Zerkms.

Answer (score 2):

```
$list = array('something 1', 'something 2', 'something 3');
shuffle($list);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($list as $item) {
    echo '<li>' . htmlspecialchars($item) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I updated the code I had because I missed some of the detail. I trying to pull in code from a database in wordpress and so the content is more than a string.

Comment: @Design Clipboard: define "more than a string". Is it a *superstring*? ;-)